# Response time very long when few users actives

Tags: php, performance, drupal, locust

I have a drupal 9 website with drupal commerce. I'm using drupal cache system.

Using the locust tools, I'm able to test the response time of some paging charging a bunch of fake users.

For some reason that I didn't found yet, as soon as there are few users on the website, the response time is really slow.

Drupal cache, aggregation, block caching are all enable

I'm working with the latest version of drupal

[image]

[image]